# SQL: How to speedup a view in PostgreSQL? My query takes +2 seconds, even for a low record count database

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables
rb_content : A simple table with movies and series (title/description/category)
rb_exclude : A table with a list of titles/descriptions to exclude from rb_content for a certain category.
I'm no SQL expert, so I'm probably using the wrong approach here to accomplish this.

```sql
SELECT title as rb_title, description as rb_description
FROM rb_content
WHERE title NOT IN (
    SELECT title
    FROM rb_content
    INNER JOIN rb_exclude
        ON  ((
            (rb_content.title ILIKE '%' || rb_exclude.txt || '%') AND
            (rb_content.category = rb_exclude.category) AND
            (rb_exclude.field = 0)
            ) OR (
            (rb_content.description ILIKE '%' || rb_exclude.txt || '%') AND
            (rb_content.category = rb_exclude.category) AND
            (rb_exclude.field = 1)
            )) AND (rb_exclude.active = 1)
);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of the logic youwant to implement.

Comment: `'%' || rb_exclude.txt || '%'` can't use indexes and will cause false positives, e.g. `assassin` would get excluded if you filter out `ass`

Comment: @tbielaszewski Yes, I'm aware of that, and is intended behavior. I specify my exclusions carefully. Concerning the indexes, yes, true. I think I found a workaround by limiting the search and exclusion query depending on the selected/requested view on my web page.
For the same visual result, the query is now executing within 70ms, and was >2500ms before.